# AutoHotKey remapping to Shift+Win

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to remap a shortcut to Shift+Win, but it's not working at all for me. Here's what I have tried:

```
^RAlt::
KeyWait Alt
KeyWait Ctrl
Send, {LShift down}{LWin down}{LWin up}{LShift up}
return
```

It seems like this works for any other trigger than `^RAlt`. However, this trigger is a valid trigger because it works for something like sending text with AHK. It seems like the problem lies with using this particular trigger *and* this action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe add a sleep

`Send, {LShift down}{LWin down}`

Sleep 50

Send, {LWin up}{LShift up}